# Find all possible relationships between two nodes in multi-parent hierarchy data model [SQL Server]

Tags: sql-server, database

I have a data model to define multi-parent hierarical data. Each record will represent a relationship of two nodes in which one will be a parent node and another will be a child node. In my case, a node can have multiple parents. I need to find all possible relationsips between two nodes.

### For example take the below table.

```
---------------------------------
| id | parent_node | child_node |
---------------------------------
| 1  | NULL        | A          |
| 2  | NULL        | B          |
| 3  | A           | C          |
| 4  | A           | D          |
| 5  | B           | D          |
| 6  | B           | E          |
| 7  | C           | G          |
| 8  | C           | H          |
| 10 | D           | I          |
| 11 | E           | I          |
| 12 | E           | J          |
---------------------------------
```

### This will form a graph like below

```
        A   B
       / \ / \    
      C   D   E
    /  \   \ / \
   G    H   I   J
```

In the above model, A and B will be the top level node and each has two children. Node D is assigned as the child of node A and B. And also node I is assigned as the child of node D and node E. All other nodes has exactly one parent.

I need to write a query to show **all possible relationship of a node with another node**.
For example,

1. A and C has a relationship, because C is child of Node A.
2. A and D has a relationship, because D is child of Node A.
3. A and G has a relatiohship, because G is the grandchild of Node A.
4. This will go for any number of levels.
5. Two nodes doesn't have any relationship, if any one node is not a child or nth-level grandchild of another.

**If two nodes doesn't have any relationship, it will not show up.**

### The final outcome for the above graph will be as below,

```
----------------------------
| parent_node | child_node |
----------------------------
| A           | C          |
| A           | D          |
| C           | G          |
| C           | H          |
| D           | I          |
| A           | G          |
| A           | H          |
| A           | I          |
| B           | D          |
| B           | E          |
| B           | I          |
| E           | I          |
| E           | J          |
| B           | J          |
----------------------------
```

I am new to SQL Server. Please help me to solve this query.

Comment: It is called a recursive cte. There are literally thousands and thousands and thousands of examples of how to do this all over this site and the rest of the internet.

Comment: @SeanLange, Thank you for your hint. I have started looking into recursive cte.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By doing some research, I was able to write the query myself. As @SeanLange pointed out in the comments, this type of query is called a recursive CTE.

If the table name is `nodes`, the following query will create the new table `relationship` and store all possible relationships in it as mentioned in my question.

```
;with cte as (
    select  child_node
    ,       parent_node
    ,       child_node as root
    from    nodes
    union all
    select  child.child_node
    ,       child.parent_node
    ,       parent.root
    from    cte parent
    join    nodes child
    on      parent.parent_node = child.child_node
)
select parent_node,
       root as child_node
into   relationship
from   cte
where  parent_node is not null;

select * from relationship;
```

Comment: Well done. Sometimes it is just knowing what to search for. Glad you solved it yourself. :D